# Jekill sort by a property specified in the variable

Tags: sorting, jekyll, liquid

I'm creating a template using Jekill. Is it possible to sort items by a property specified in the variable like this:

```
<!-- Collection identity -->
{% assign collection_id = page.id %}

<!-- Select pages and sort them by a value provided for the collection -->
{% assign product_pages = (site.pages | sort: [collection_id]) %}
```

The sorting doesn't work (compile error).

The task is to have some pages that define categories with headers like this one:

```
---
layout: collection
id: sale
...
---
```

Then some pages could be in one or more collections and so as to define their sort order inside each collectino the page would have a header like this:

```
---
layout: item
sale: 100
news: 30
general: 1000
...
---
```

Sale, News, General etc have the same template that should be automatically generated and they could have sorted collection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to sort items by a property, but pages do not have an `id` property, you can however, sort them by another property, e.g.: *name*.

## Unsorted:

```
{% for p in site.pages %}
{{p.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

## Sorted by `page.name`:

```
{% assign product_pages = site.pages | sort: 'name' %}

{% for p in product_pages %}
{{p.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

## Update

To sort with a custom `id` property added to pages:

```
{% assign product_pages = site.pages | sort: 'id' %}
```

Comment: Well, it sorts by a predefined field by not by dynamical. I've put more info on the topic to clarify the task.

Comment: If you define your own `id` key in frontmatter then just change the sorting key with that one and it will work.

Comment: As I understand it means that for each category page like "sale", "news", "general" etc there should be own template file but I'd like to have one template for all of them and taking page.id it should sort the pages in the corresponding manner: if page.id is "sale" then by "sale" property etc.

Comment: So you need to filter them before sorting. It is a bit confusing as I suspect that you are trying to filter posts not pages?

Comment: Well, it's not a problem to filter before sorting or after one; the problem is to find a way to sort a set of pages by a property that is stored in a variable...

Comment: No, it gives  Liquid Exception: Liquid error (line 8): comparison of Jekyll::Page with Jekyll::Page failed in /_layouts/collection.html